# c++ struct after struct definition?

Tags: c++, struct

I have seen the following code:

```
struct orb_metadata {
    const char *o_name;     /**< unique object name */
    const size_t o_size;        /**< object size */
};

#define ORB_DEFINE(_name, _struct)          \
    const struct orb_metadata __orb_##_name = { \
        #_name,                 \
        sizeof(_struct)             \
    }; struct hack
```

I could understand the MACRO part where a new orb_metadata is created and initialized.
But what is this struct hack?

Comment: When the macro is called with a semicolon afterwards, it looks like a forward declaration.

Comment: Show `ORB_DEFINE` usage, please

Comment: what is forward declaration @   πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @MadhuKumar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration